# Split en golang

Tags: go

Tengo el nombre de un archivo hola_mundo.txt y pretendo guardar en la variable a := hola en la variable b := mundo
Como puedo hacer esto en golang. He revisado Split pero no lo consigo.
Pueden por favor ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Es con `Split()` pero el problema que tienes, es que has de importar el paquete strings y llamar correctamente a Split. ej: strings.Split().

> **Importante**: Split() la S va en mayuscula, si no dará un error de referencia

El codigo que necesitas seria algo como esto:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)


func main(){

    fileName := "Hola.txt"
    Nombre := strings.Split(fileName,".")
    fmt.Println("Result : ", Nombre)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    nombreArchivoExtension := "hola_mundo.txt"

    // remover la extension .txt
    nombreArchivo := strings.Split(nombreArchivoExtension, ".")[0]

    // Hacer split del nombre
    partesDelNombre := strings.Split(nombreArchivo, "_")

    fmt.Println("El {hola}: " + partesDelNombre[0])
    fmt.Println("El {mundo}: " + partesDelNombre[1])
}

/*
Output:
El {hola}: hola
El {mundo}: mundo
*/
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).